# How to set my custom phtml to header?

Tags: magento2, header

I want to set my custom phtml to header in magento 2?
i want to display my phtml in all pages so i want to add my phtml in header.

i am trying to search in core files but i can't get it.

In layout how to set template to add phtml in header.I want to add my phtml without changes of admin blocks.

Is that possible to do this? How can i do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use default.xml to add your phtml in header

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="header.container">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="example" after="-" template="Company_Example::example.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
</body> 
</page>
```

In `referenceBlock` name you can use `header.container` or `header.panel`

Comment: What is file location of default.xml ??